# How to fix windows explorer crash?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-explorer, crash

I am running Windows 7 Professional Service Pack 1 on Lenovo T400.
I am facing a problem whenever I tried to access my wifi properties, it caused Windows Explorer to stop working, and then restarting all by itself. The wifi works fine. However I can never access the properties windows for the wifi.
I have been searching through the internet for the same problem but so far I have not found anyone getting the same issue.
I have never faced this problem before.
I can provide more information upon request to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Below is my crash log:

```
Description
Faulting Application Path:  C:\Windows\explorer.exe

Problem signature
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   Explorer.EXE
Application Version:    6.1.7601.17567
Application Timestamp:  4d672ee4
Fault Module Name:  KERNELBASE.dll
Fault Module Version:   6.1.7601.18015
Fault Module Timestamp: 50b8479b
Exception Code: c06d007e
Exception Offset:   0000000000009e5d
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  18441
Additional Information 1:   64af
Additional Information 2:   64af7d695b0acc52a6637852b7a00c5e
Additional Information 3:   b91c
Additional Information 4:   b91c2125423869bb88ea046d92876c0c

Extra information about the problem
Bucket ID:  90452051
```

Comment: please download this reg file from my SkyDrive:

http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full.reg

and make a double click on the file to import it. When the Windows Explorer crashes, Windows Error Reporting Service creates a dmp file under C:\Localdumps. Please upload the dump file (compressed 7z or RAR to reduce the size).

After you generated the dumps, download and import this regfile:

http://cid-128fc518635be2dc.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/MS%20Foren/Registry/WER%5E_Explorer_full_uninstall.reg

to stop the dump creation.

Comment: @magicandre1981 After I run the script, it also make the Windows Explorer to stop working and restart itself when I access the Folder Explorer. It is irreversible even if I ran the un-install script or restart the laptop. Somehow after I try to produce the original crash, I manage to get back my Folders Explorer. So this is the link to the dump with oldest modified timestamp which I guess recorded the original crash: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7390098/explorer.exe.4372.rar And this link to the dump among others which recorded the second crash: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7390098/explorer.exe.2024.rar

Answer (score 1):

ok, you have 2 different crashes. 1 comes from apple and 1 from Intel Wifi tools:

```
APPLICATION_VERIFIER_HANDLES_NULL_HANDLE (303)
NULL handle passed as parameter. A valid handle must be used.
This stop is generated if the function on the top of the stack passed a
NULL handle to system routines. 
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
Arg3: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
Arg4: 0000000000000000, Not used. 
Debugger Dbgportaldb Connection::Open failed 80004005
Database Dbgportaldb not connected

FAULTING_IP: 
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+6fb
000007fe`f866ae03 cc              int     3

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fef866ae03 (verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx+0x00000000000006fb)
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 0000000000000000

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {AUSNAHME}  Haltepunkt  Im Quellprogramm wurde ein Haltepunkt erreicht.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - Mindestens ein Argument ist ung ltig.

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  0000000000000000

NTGLOBALFLAG:  2000100

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  48004

APP:  explorer.exe

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000000008ec

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  STATUS_BREAKPOINT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_STATUS_BREAKPOINT

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000007fef868201e to 000007fef866ae03

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!RtlDispatchException
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch
verifier!VerifierStopMessageEx
verifier!AVrfpHandleSanityChecks
verifier!AVrfpNtSetEvent
KERNELBASE!SetEvent
ShellStreams64!DllCanUnloadNow
ShellStreams64
ShellStreams64
shell32!CRegFolder::_CreateCachedRegFolder
shell32!CRegFolder::_BindToItem
shell32!CRegFolder::BindToObject
shell32!CShellItem::_BindToHandlerLegacy
shell32!CShellItem::BindToHandler
shell32!CShellItem::_GetPropertyStoreWorker
shell32!CShellItem::GetPropertyStoreForKeys
shell32!CShellItem::GetProperty
EXPLORERFRAME!ShouldPinItem
EXPLORERFRAME!CNscEnumTask::InternalResumeRT
EXPLORERFRAME!CRunnableTask::Run
shell32!CShellTask::TT_Run
shell32!CShellTaskThread::ThreadProc
shell32!CShellTaskThread::s_ThreadProc
shlwapi!ExecuteWorkItemThreadProc
ntdll!RtlpTpWorkCallback
ntdll!TppWorkerThread
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart



IMAGE_NAME:  ShellStreams64.dll

    Loaded symbol image file: ShellStreams64.dll
    Image path: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Internet Services\ShellStreams64.dll
    Image name: ShellStreams64.dll
    Timestamp:        Tue Dec 18 01:38:54 2012 



EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffffffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 000007fefdfb9e5d (KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x0000000000000039)
   ExceptionCode: c06d007e
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 1
   Parameter[0]: 000000000af6d6d0

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  explorer.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc06d007e - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc06d007e - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_PARAMETER1:  000000000af6d6d0

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  explorer.exe

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 000000000b049cf1 to 000007fefdfb9e5d

FAULTING_THREAD:  0000000000001f84

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_APPLICATION_FAULT

STACK_TEXT:  
ntdll!RtlRaiseException
KERNELBASE!RaiseException
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
wlihvui
wlihvui
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
wlihvui!DllUnregisterServer
ole32!CServerContextActivator::CreateInstance
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
ole32!CApartmentActivator::CreateInstance
ole32!CProcessActivator::CCICallback
ole32!CProcessActivator::AttemptActivation
ole32!CProcessActivator::ActivateByContext
ole32!CProcessActivator::CreateInstance
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
ole32!CClientContextActivator::CreateInstance
ole32!ActivationPropertiesIn::DelegateCreateInstance
ole32!ICoCreateInstanceEx
ole32!CoCreateInstance
wlanui!IHVHelper::IHVHlpInitialize
wlanui!CAdvancedUI::ShowAdvancedUI
wlanui!WLInvokeProfileUI
wlanui!WLInvokeProfileUIFromXMLFile
wlanui!WlanUIEditProfile
wlanpref!ShowWlanProfileDialog
wlanpref!CPreflistContextMenu::InvokeCommand
shell32!CShellExecute::_InvokeInProcExec
shell32!CShellExecute::_InvokeCtxMenu
shell32!CShellExecute::_DoExecute
shell32!CShellExecute::s_ExecuteThreadProc
shlwapi!WrapperThreadProc
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart


IMAGE_NAME:  wlihvui.dll


    Loaded symbol image file: wlihvui.dll
    Image path: C:\Windows\System32\wlihvui.dll
    Image name: wlihvui.dll
    Timestamp:        Thu Jul 28 05:54:41 2011 (4E30DD81)
    CheckSum:         0012A8F6
    ImageSize:        00132000
    File version:     14.2.0.0
    Product version:  14.2.0.0
    File flags:       0 (Mask 3F)
    File OS:          4 Unknown Win32
    File type:        2.0 Dll
    File date:        00000000.00000000
    Translations:     0409.04b0
    CompanyName:      Intel(R) Corporation
    ProductName:      Intel(R) PROSet/Wireless
    InternalName:     WLIHVUI
    OriginalFilename: WLIHVUI.DLL
    ProductVersion:   14, 2, 0, 0
    FileVersion:      14, 2, 0, 0
    FileDescription:  Intel(R) PROSet/Wireless WLIHVUI Module
    LegalCopyright:   Copyright (c) Intel Corporation 2007-2011
```

so update the Apple tool (or remove it if also reinstalling the latest version doesn't fix it) and install the latest Wifi driver from Intel.

Comment: Thans a bunch. I managed to upgrade the driver for the wifi card and now it works just fine. I really appreciate your help. ^^ I cannot vote up for your answer since I does not have enough reputation so sorry about that. Btw, how can you decrypt the debug file I wonder?

Comment: I've used WinDbg from the **Debugging Tools for Windows** to analyze the dump.